# Extract multiple integers from a string

Tags: c#

I am having a file which has the following lines:

```
29x13x26
11x11x14
27x2x5
6x10x13
15x19x10
26x29x15
8x23x6
17x8x26
20x28x3
23x12x24
11x17x3
19x23x28
25x2x25
1x15x3
25x14x4
```

I am parsing the file into a list. What i want to do it get only the numbers from each line.

For example in the first line i want to take 29, 13, 26

Here is the code i have

```
    //Get line by line all gift sizes from txt and add them to a list
    foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("GiftSizes.txt"))
    {
        //Insert values into list
        dimensionsList.Add(line);
    }

    foreach(var giftDimension in dimensionsList){
               //get the numbers from each line
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`string.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com//dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___) which will split your string into chunks and omits the delimiter - in your case the character `'x'`.

```
//Get line by line all gift sizes from txt and add them to a list
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines("GiftSizes.txt"))
{
    //Insert values into list
    dimensionsList.Add(line);
}

foreach(var giftDimension in dimensionsList)
{
    int[] numbers = giftDimension.Split('x').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: thank you for the correction - I've deleted my comment. Even so, I still don't like `Convert.ToInt32` because you can't specify a `NumberStyles` value - and it indicates failure via exceptions which may be undesirable when processing untrusted or unverified input (due to exceptions' performance impact) - whereas `TryParse` is far preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Regex:

```
static readonly _threeDigits = new Regex( @"^(\d+)x(\d+)x(\d+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled );

static IEnumerable<(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 z)> ReadValues( String fileContents )
{
    MatchCollection matches = _threeDigits.Match( fileContents );
    foreach( Match m in matches )
    {
        yield return (
            x: Int32.Parse( m.Groups[1], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ), // Groups start at [1], not [0].
            y: Int32.Parse( m.Groups[2], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture  ),
            z: Int32.Parse( m.Groups[3], NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture  )
        );
    }
}

static List<(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 z)> ReadValuesAsList( String fileContents )
{
    return ReadValuesAsList( fileContents ).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function on the string

```
foreach(var giftDimension in dimensionsList) 
{
int[] numberArray=giftDimension.Split('x'); 
}
```

Comment: to quote Satpal: "You would need to parse the string to the number after split()".